# ng-repeat duplicating items after page reload

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I have an angularjs application, with a node.js and express backend, so I'm not using angular's routings. When I refresh the page using the browser's refresh button, my Items on the page that are loaded in a ng-repeat duplicate.

I'm not sure why this occurs, but I'm wondering what happens to the controller when the page is reloaded? Is the old controller destroyed, and a new one created, or is another controller added, which could be causing the duplications?

Here is part of my html file, as well as the relvevant controller code:

(trans.html)

```
<div class="pure-u-1-2" ng-repeat="trans in transactions | filter:searchText">
        <div class="transaction" ng-style="{'border-style': 'solid', 'border-color': categoryColours[trans.category.name]}">
            <h2 id="transName">{{ trans.name }}</h2>
            <h4>{{ trans.description }}</h4>
            <h4>{{ trans.date }}</h4>
            <div class="pure-u-1-1">
                <h3 id="categoryLabel" ng-style="{'background-color': categoryColours[trans.category.name], color: 'white' }">{{ trans.category.name }}</p>
                    <h2 id="transType" ng-style="{'background-color': categoryColours[trans.category.name], color: 'white' }">{{trans.type}}: £{{ trans.amount }}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="clearFix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(transController)

```
function TransController($scope, socket) {
 var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    $scope.transactions = [];
    $scope.currentMonth = months[getMonth()];
    $scope.categories = {};
    $scope.categoryColours = {};
    $scope.types = [{
        name: "Income"
    }, {
        name: "Spending"
    }];
    init();

    function init() {

        console.log("emitting init functs");
        monthDataRequest($scope.currentMonth, 'init');
        socket.emit('getCategories', {});
    };

    //sends a data request to the server the months data
    function monthDataRequest(month, type) {
        socket.emit('transDataRequest', {
            request: 'transactions',
            month: month,
            type: type
        });
    };

    function getMonth() {
        var d = new Date();
        return d.getMonth();
    };

    socket.on('categories', function (data) {
        var categories = [];
        for (var key in data.categories) {
            console.log("key: ", key);
            categories.push(key);
        }
        $scope.categories = categories;
        $scope.categoryColours = data.categories;
        console.log($scope.categories);
        $scope.safeApply();
    });


    socket.on('transResponse', function (data) {
        console.log("Data response received. month: ", data.month, " type: ", data.type);
        if (data.type == 'init') {
            console.log("setting up initial data");
            $scope.transactions = [];
            console.log("received data: ", data.data);
            $scope.currentMonth = data.month;
            $scope.transactions = [];
            var tran = data.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < tran.length; i++) {
                $scope.transactions.push(tran[i]);
                console.log("loop ", i, "data i: ", tran[i]);
            };

            $scope.safeApply();
            console.log($scope.transactions);
            console.log("CURRENT MONTH " + $scope.currentMonth);
        } else {
            console.log("was not initial data");
            $scope.transactions = [];
            console.log(data);
            var tran = data.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < tran.length; i++) {
                $scope.transactions.push(tran[i]);
                console.log(tran[i]);
            };
            $scope.safeApply();
            console.log($scope.transactions);
            console.log("CURRENT MONTH " + $scope.currentMonth);
        }
    });
```

I would really appreciate any advice on why there are duplicate transactions being shown after the page is refreshed.

Comment: Why you don't use `$scope.transactions = data.data` instead of `for` loop?

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried that, makes so more sense, but I'm still getting the same problem? It duplicates the transactions 3 times after the page reload

Comment: There are advantages of using for loop i.e. when you have a huge list of elements that animates on enter/leave or similar case when you assign whole object to variable it recreates all elements which might cause a mayhem while changing only values in loop won't do it

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird, if you reload page controller gets initiated again so:

```
$scope.transactions = [];
```

would null the transactions - BTW transResponse

```
$scope.transactions = [];
console.log("received data: ", data.data);
$scope.currentMonth = data.month;
$scope.transactions = [];
```

you null it twice without any other actions, i think you can omit at least one of those

My only guess at this point will be either socket provides you with duplicated transactions or you store it somehow in service (can't tell since you didn't provided socket service code)

You can catch me directly on angularjs IRC channgel irc.freenode.net #angularjs -> maurycyg

Comment: Thanks, that was a bit of desperation trying to fix this bug. Is there another way I can contact you/show my server side implementation?

Comment: Google Talk maybe, add [g] at end of my nick to get my email

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the [same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187995/ng-repeat-repeating-data-with-duplicate-entries). Where you able to resolve this ?

Comment: If you can reproduce it on plunker, codepen, jsfiddle I can easily debug it for you, I'm keen to find the problem behind that, previous OP wasn't to helpful with that ;)