# ng -repeat repeating data with duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to display a JSON data using AngularJS ng repeat but the records are getting duplicated. 
**Note:** It works fine the very first time the page is loaded. When I try to reload the page the items get duplicated.

Here is my JSON data:

```
    [{
    "EmployeeName": "Jishnu",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 76,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}, {
    "EmployeeName": "Sini",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 56,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}, {
    "EmployeeName": "Abhilash",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 12,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}, {
    "EmployeeName": "Abhilash",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 10,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}, {
    "EmployeeName": "abhila",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 6,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}, {
    "EmployeeName": "Ajay ",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 5,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}, {
    "EmployeeName": "Abel",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 4,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}, {
    "EmployeeName": "ABDUL",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 3,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}, {
    "EmployeeName": "Administrator",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 2,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}, {
    "EmployeeName": "ABI",
    "CategoryId": 0,
    "Points": 1,
    "DateAdded": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "DateModified": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
    "Id": 0
}]
```

Here is the AngularJS code:

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('ReportCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window) {

     $scope.employeePoints = [];
     $scope.searchText = [];


     // $http starts here

     $http({
             // set the parameter for request
             method: 'POST',
             url: 'Report/GetEmployeePoints',
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
             },
             data: {}
         })
         .then(function(resp) {

                 // Success callback -- starts here
                 $scope.employeePoints = resp.data.response;

             },
             function(error) {
                 // Error callback
             });



 }]);
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="point in employeePoints">
    <td>
        <span class="name">{{point.EmployeeName}}</span>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden-phone">
        {{point.Points}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the console log data of the response from the web service:

```
[{"EmployeeName":"Jishnu","CategoryId":0,"Points":76,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":280},{"EmployeeName":"Sini","CategoryId":0,"Points":56,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":78},{"EmployeeName":"Abhilash","CategoryId":0,"Points":12,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":100},{"EmployeeName":"Abhilash","CategoryId":0,"Points":10,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":72},{"EmployeeName":"abhila","CategoryId":0,"Points":6,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":323},{"EmployeeName":"Ajay ","CategoryId":0,"Points":5,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":97},{"EmployeeName":"Abel","CategoryId":0,"Points":4,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":297},{"EmployeeName":"ABDUL","CategoryId":0,"Points":3,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":14},{"EmployeeName":"Administrator","CategoryId":0,"Points":2,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":1},{"EmployeeName":"ABI","CategoryId":0,"Points":1,"DateAdded":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","DateModified":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Id":178}]
```

Comment: Where do you load the data? Is it locally stored?

Comment: Can you create a working demo?

Comment: @devqon I'm fetching the data from a web service. I checked it twice, no duplicate entries

Comment: @niyasc I'm not able to create a working demo

Comment: Why `ids`  are `0` in all objects inside array?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak can that be an issue ?

Comment: No that should not be the issue. Employee 'Abhilash' is duplicated though in your json

Comment: What happens if you print `$scope.employeePoints` in the console before your $http ? Is there still data after your second page reload ?

Comment: try to see from fiddler or chrome dev tool bar if 2 calls are being made to the service.  If no, then the html page is caching the data on reload. you need to clear it on refresh.

Comment: @AndrewDonovan before the call there is no data, it gets filled up only after the data. Data fetched from the server is fine. When using ng repeat it duplicates the entry

Comment: try a json parse on that data?

Comment: Its probably a tiny detail you left out. This bug should not happen. You are assigning the data from the server to your variable, it should always be what it recieves. Unless there's cache involved, which i doubt. Did you test it in private navigation to make sure ?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant @AndrewDonovan

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/8qwzj2q9/) with your provided data.  No dupes except Abhilash.  If you can edit this to better represent your code to try and reproduce, it would be helpful.

Comment: @iJade, im just saying there is probably a detail in your code that you are not seeing right now. Your code is pretty straight forward and should not cause duplications

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your case is, but following code will do the trick for you

If you would be able to refactor `index` i.e `id` to your json object, you can use [`track by`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)  syntax for the same.

```
<tr ng-repeat="point in employeePoints track by point.id">
    <td>
        <span class="name">{{point.EmployeeName}}</span>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden-phone">
        {{point.Points}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

can do

```
ng-repeat="point in employeePoints track by $index"
```

It would be better to use your actual data `ids` instead you can use angularjs `$index` for the same in case if you would not be able to fetch `ids`.

Comment: should point.id be like row index. or can it be user ids in random unique order ?

Comment: Yes probably `point.id` will be your actual `employeid` from the db/service, and `$index` will be the row index inside `ng-repeat`!

Comment: still not working. It's still getting repeated. I have like 10 items to display. But each item is getting repeating 10 times. So, total 100 items are getting displayed

Comment: That is strange, it would be easy to debug if you can share actual code, can you share the response from the `service`? actual console log

Comment: Updated the actual console.log of the data received from the web service